# Weather forecasts of upcoming passes

Tags: deep-space-network

Does NASA currently use weather forecasts of an upcoming passes to assign appropriate channel data rate with Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter (MRO) and Mars Odyssey Orbiter (ODY)?

I was looking at DSN NOW https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html
and noticed that the ODY used one telemetry data rate during first half of the pass and used different data rate during second half. Was that achieved by using weather forecasts?

Comment: Can you please define the acronyms MRI and ODY?

Comment: I have edited my question to add acronyms.

Comment: In many communications system, link quality is measured directly. At the start of the communications session, the 2 stations work out the highest speed at which they can communicate reliably (by testing at different speeds). If the error rate becomes unacceptable during the session, speed is reduced. I would be surprised if NASA used something as indirect as the weather forecast instead.

Comment: Thanks @Hobbes. In some documents, I have read about using weather forecasts to improve performance of Ka-band. There are documents where using weather forecast to vary channel data rate has been discussed. I just wanted to know if the concept is in documents only or has been already implemented.

Comment: @MarkAdler Could you give some insights on the issue ?